# How to dynamically convert List<MyClass> to List<KeyValue>?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dynamic

If I have, for example, this class

```
public class User{
    int Id;
    string Name;
    short Age;
}
```

and a collection of `User`:

```
public class UserCollection: List<User>{...}
```

Can I create a `List<KeyValue>` (`KeyValue` is my class)  from an `UserCollection` choosing which property is the `Key` (or `Value`)?

I tried with this code:

```
private List<KeyValue> ReadCollection(dynamic collection, string keyName, string valueName)
{
    List<KeyValue> list = new List<KeyValue>();

    for(int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
    {
        dynamic elem = collection[i];
        // I can't use this notation, but only elem.Id
        int key = elem[keyName]; 
        // I can't use this notation, but only elem.Name
        string value = elem[valueName];

        list.Add(new KeyValue(key, value));
     }

     return list;
}

List<KeyValue> list = ReadCollection(userCollection, "Id", "Name");
```

but it doesn't work. It is possible to choose which property put inside my `KeyValue` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite this using `Func` instead of all that dynamic stuff.

```
private List<KeyValue> ReadCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, int> keyFunc, Func<T, string> valueFunc)
{

    List<KeyValue> list = new List<KeyValue>();

    foreach (T elem in collection)
    {
        int key = keyFunc(elem);
        string value = valueFunc(elem);

        list.Add(new KeyValue(key, value));
     }

     return list;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
List<KeyValue> list = ReadCollection<User>(userCollection, u => u.Id, u => u.Name);
```

Benefits:

- All code is typed, so no runtime exceptions;
- You have full IntelliSense support;
- It supports virtually any collection type, also LINQ enumerables.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as the source collection is not a key-value collection, you can not use the `[]` notation to access properties. That's why the notation doesn't work. You could try to use reflection methods like `GetProperty` to access the value dynamically:

```
var key = elem.GetType().GetProperty(keyName).GetValue(elem, null);
var value = elem.GetType().GetProperty(valueName).GetValue(elem, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would at least make the method generic, rather than take a dynamic object.

Then you can generate simple LINQ expressions to access the properties you require, and use these to get the key and value for each entry:

```
private static List<KeyValue> ReadCollection<T>(IList<T> collection, string keyName, string valueName)
{       
    List<KeyValue> list = new List<KeyValue>();

    Func<T, int> keyFunction = GenerateLambda<T, int>(keyName);
    Func<T, string> valueFunction = GenerateLambda<T, string>(valueName);

    for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
    {
        T elem = collection[i];
        int key = keyFunction(elem);
        string value = valueFunction(elem);
        list.Add(new KeyValue(key, value));
    }
    return list;

    // or simpler
    //return collection.Select(elem => new KeyValue(keyFunction(elem), valueFunction(elem))).ToList();
}

private static Func<T, TProp> GenerateLambda<T, TProp>(string propertyName)
{
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TProp>>(Expression.PropertyOrField(p, propertyName), p);
    return expr.Compile();
}

List<KeyValue> list = ReadCollection(userCollection, "Id", "Name");
```

[Working .NET Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sv5nmJ)

Comment: Essentially you're just doing what Select does already except this is error prone. What if I pass in "ID" instead of "Id", or worse I pass in "Name" as the first parameter and "Id" second. Don't get me wrong, it's a nice solution when needing something completely dynamic in the event that a user selects the key field and selects the value field but it would need a lot of type and error checking to ensure the user couldn't mess it up.

Comment: @StephenBrickner yes you are correct, it is error-prone. That is what comes with allowing users to choose what they want / use your program. I was just answering the fundamental question posed by the OP, how to generate the list when the property names are __unknown__. You are welcome to post another answer which incorporates these extra requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue much more simply by just using Select.

```
List<KeyValue> list = userCollection
                         .Select(x => new KeyValue(x.ID, x.Name))
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it, but not very dynamic - what if they want to use different properties for key/value ?

Comment: Then you would select them. Passing in "Id", "Name" is the same as selecting them in the key value pair above.